# Access child property with conflicting name from parent class in PHP

Tags: php, oop, class, inheritance

Is it possible to access a child property from a parent class, when both parent and child share the same property name, but with different visibility?

Consider the following example:

```
abstract class A {
    private $n = 1;

    public function getN() {
        return $this->n;
    }
}

class B extends A {
    protected $n = 2;
}

$b = new B;
echo $b->getN(); // returns 1
```

`getN()` returns `1`, because it returns the value of its own private `$n`.

Is it possible to get the value of the *child's* `protected $n` instead, from the parent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, you can't. You would have to declare `A::$n` `protected` or `public`, because private members always have precedence. If you declare `A::$n` public, then `B::$n` will also need to be public, since you cannot override a property with less visibility than its parent. You can do it only by using the [Reflection API](http://php.net/Reflection):

```
abstract class A {
    private $n = 1;

    public function getN() {
        $ref = new ReflectionProperty($this, 'n');
        $ref->setAccessible(true);
        echo $ref->getValue($this);
    }
}

class B extends A {
    protected $n = 2;
}

$b = new B;
echo $b->getN(); // 2
```

Comment: Thank you, that is perfectly suitable for what I want to do as Reflection was already used on that class for other purposes.