# How to get non-static variable from inherited class?

Tags: php, oop

In such a case, how to access the property in the first class from the second class?

```
class First
{
    public $var = 'First Non-Static Property';

    public function __construct()
    {
        echo $this->var;
    }
}

class Second extends First
{
    public $var = 'Second Non-Static Property';

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::$var;
    }
}

$object = new Second();
```

Im getting an error;

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Access to undeclared static property: First::$var in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/tests/index.php on line 19

Comment: Because it does not work like that, `parent::` only applicable for overwritten methods, not properties

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access child property with conflicting name from parent class in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6876590/access-child-property-with-conflicting-name-from-parent-class-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should brush up on OOP, inheritance and overriding. When you create an instance of a class, the created object contains all of the attributes and methods defined in it, as well as any other methods and attributes of it's parent class which it is extending (as long as they have a scope of public and protected)

In your case, the class "Second" does inherit class "First" **BUT** it does re-initialize the value of your "var" class property that you initially defined in the First class. Therefore, you're basically done with accessing the value that var has in the the first class, because you set it to a new value in the child (Second) class.

If you do for some reason want to access it, you can remove the

```php
public $var = 'Second Non-Static Property';
```

part in the second class, and then in the second class in the constructor have something like:

```php
public function __construct()
{
    echo $this->var;
}
```

this will print "First Non-Static Property"

and then you can redefine the var property of the Second class as you with after this call.

Second option that comes to mind is you to call the parent constructor

```php
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}
```

That will also print out the "First Non-Static Property".

Some additional mentions of the difference between parent:: and $this-> can be found here
[PHP Accessing Parent Class Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6456939/php-accessing-parent-class-variable)

Comment: First of all, thank you for your response. In other words, what you want to say in the simplest way is as if the property is already at the top because I inherited it and I am changing its value.

class Test {
public $var = 'First Non-Static Property';
public $var = 'Second Non-Static Property';
}

and in this case, the value of the $var property is automatically changed to "Second Non-Static Property". Did I get right?

Comment: You're welcome :) 

Yup. You changed the value of your $var property in the child class. You re-defined it. And then you basically can't access the value that is initially set in the parent class. I would avoid re-defining a class property again in the child class anyways, don't see a real value in doing so. If you really want to change the value of a public or protected class property in the child class, you can always do that with $this->var = 'my new val'; 

Good luck with your learning :)

Comment: You are right, I wish myself good luck in learning and I hope :) thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You access parent class non-static attributes like this:

```
<?php
class First
{
    public $var2 = 'First Non-Static Property';

    public function __construct()
    {
        echo $this->var2;
    }
}

class Second extends First
{
    public $var = 'Second Non-Static Property';

    public function __construct()
    {
        echo $this->var2;
    }
}

$object = new Second();
?>
```

If you access variable named var then it will gonna return child class string due to overloading, so if you give different name to variable then you access parent public and protected non-static variables like this.

Hope this is helpful

Comment: I doubt that changing the variables is the solution the OP is searching for

Comment: Yes because he wants to access parent variable and giving same name to child class variable and want to access into constructor so $this is going to return child class variable and he wants to access parent class non static variable so it is the way to access parent class variable

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it